# Generate two or more items returned by function map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I would like to render two itens in a even div, but this is rendered each one in a single div using the method array.map(). My code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'
function Home() {
const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('')
const [containerArray, setContainerArray] = useState ([])

function registerUsers () {
    setContainerArray([...containerArray, userName, userEmail])
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Register your users and handle them</h1>
        <div id='div1'>
        <div id='div2'>
           <div id='array-div'> {containerArray.map((item)=>{return  <div id='array-div2'><li>{item} 
        </li></div>})}</div>
 </div>)}
```

export default Home

Comment: Do you want the containerArray.map(...) to return 2 li items inside the <div id='array-div2'> ?
Or it would be nice if you can explain a little bit more about it.

Comment: I want two itens in a unique div, bu this render each item in a one div.

Comment: Okay, is the items fixed to two ? or you want to increase them in future?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the li alone in the array.map:

```
<div id='array-div'>
    {
        containerArray.map((item) => (
            <li>
                {item} 
            </li>
        )
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For returning two `<li></li>` with your unique `<div></div>`. We need to first convert our 1D array into a 1X2D array so that we can return two items at once.

Here is the implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-booth-hyxg5?file=/src/App.js

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10];
const arr2D = [];
while (arr.length) {
  arr2D.push(arr.splice(0, 2));
}
return arr2D.map(items => {
  const [firstItem = null, secondItem = null] = items;
  return (
    <div>
      {firstItem && <li>{firstItem}</li>}
      {secondItem && <li>{secondItem}</li>}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Now just replace the `arr` with our `containerArray`.

I hope this will help